# How start the working on label in cocoa application for mac os?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am creating a dialog base cocoa application for mac os. But I am new in xcode. I don't know any thing about Xcode. I have created the cocoa application, these are the following file created:

```
AppDelegate.h
AppDelegate.m
MainMenu.xib
main.m
```

Also I have created the dialog using MainMenu.xib and put the two label and two button on dialog box. I want to display the some customize text in label field. But I do not know where to put the code even I don't know where to start the coding to display the text in label. 
Please someone help to me how to write the text in label.

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_actions_and_outlets.htm

Comment: Here is the best explanation for beginner   http://www.raywenderlich.com/27388/core-controls-in-mac-os-x-part-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build application yourself it's best to spend some time learning.

I recommend to read Apple guides they are best, here some, try first two:

- [Start Developing Mac Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/chapters/01_Introduction.html)

  - [Your First Mac App](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/Introduction.html)
  - Write Objective-C Code
  - Acquire Foundational Programming Skills
- Mac App Programming Guide
- Mac Technology Overview
- Window Programming Guide
- View Programming Guide

Otherwise hire experienced developer.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the start, reading documentation, books, blogposts and tutorials.

Good luck.